# swift 3 set transparent or blur effect for tableview

Tags: macos, swift3, xcode8

this is a screenshot of "Finder"

[image]

how can i realize this background effect ?
and what is the name of this? blur, transparent, ... ?

Comment: This has nothing to do with Swift, it's in AppKit and it's called NSVisualEffectView:  https://developer.apple.com/reference/appkit/nsvisualeffectview Super easy to use: just put the view where you need it, under the other ones. :)

Comment: thats very easy - if somebody knows how it works ! thank you very much :)